# add prefix to filename, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to add a prefix to the filename of a file, before I send it to the server, I have an input field like this:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadControlId">
```

And if I do this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("uploadControlId");
console.log('file: ' + element);
```

I get the output:

```
file: [object HTMLInputElement]
```

I can read the filename by splitting the element, but since the element is a url, I have no idea how I can change the name.

splitting:

```
var element = document.getElementById("uploadControlId");
var elements = element.value.split("\\");
var fileName = parts[elements.length - 1];
```

Comment: What are you doing with the file on the server? You're probably better off doing this on the server side.

Comment: It's stored inside a a sharepoint list, when I retrive it from that list later I need to look at the prefix so I know where I should place it on my site

Comment: Add a hidden input with the data you need and send that along with the file

Comment: How would that work? Where do I add the input?

Comment: In the form `<input type="hidden" value="prefix1234" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the value of an file input, becase of security reasons. You can do your own AJAX script to post a file with other name, but not using the standard browser/form functionality. In your case there's a simple solution, just add an hidden field and pass the name trough this filed. Value of this filed can be set on submit.

```
<input id="uploadControlId" type="file" >
<input id="uploadFilename" type="hidden" value="">
```

there's a tag jquery, so I'll use jquery

```
$('#yourFormId').submit(function(){
   var filename = "prefix_" + $($("#uploadControlId").val().split("\\")).last();
   $('#uploadFilename').val(filename);
   return true;
});
```

or you can do something similar